# crankbrothers 1 vs 1 SE

Tags: pedals, identify-this-bike

Most stores have Candy1 for $49, and Candy1SE for $39.

but i can't find the difference.

the SE have a golden spring, just like the Candy2. The plain Candy1 has a silver one.

Candy 1:

$49
[image: Candy 1]

Candy 1 SE:

$39
[image]

Comment: their site only shows 1,2,3,11. no mention of SE anywhere.

Comment: question still open, but i couldn't care less now that i've win the bid on a Bebop pair at ebay. $15 + $11 on a rebuild kit. now just need to find the cleats.

Comment: performancebike.com shows SE as 304g/pair, and regular candy 1 at 262g/pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They finally replied to my email i send before starting this question.

SE is simply the 1, from the last collection. They changed the names from SE, SL, etc... to 1, 2, 3, 11...

Answer (score 1):

I think [Candy 1 SE](http://www.performancebike.com/bikes/Product_10052_10551_1089834_-1_1589016_1586500_400264) is a special edition where colors are changed from standard [Candy 1](http://www.crankbrothers.com/pedals_candy1.php) as you can see in the links provided. Candy 1 SE is not even listed at [Crank Brothers website](http://www.crankbrothers.com/). So if you fancy a more exclusive color set and it's cheaper go for the SE!

Comment: Most likely it's a "cost-reduced" unit to meet a price point.  One can never guess what has been changed to reduce the price -- sometimes nothing, sometimes bling, sometimes overall quality.

Comment: (Though from the pictures you can see that the bows of the upper unit are polished, while on the lower one they're clearly stamped metal.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks i think it's just the lightning artifact. at least the one almost facing the camera seems polished.

Comment: @DanielRHicks price could also be lower to sell stock of older SE units, it may be a 2011, 2010 or older model. Most brands are selling their 2012 models now.

Comment: @gcb -- Look carefully at the sides of the bows.  On the bottom pedal you can see the roughness on the sides where the metal was sheared (look at the top bow of the two), but not on the top pedal.  Look at the bends -- you can see crimp in the bottom photo where the metal was bent.  And the edges are sharper on the bottom pedal -- not as heavily polished.  Of course it's likely that the top photo was "airbrushed", but probably only to eliminate bad reflections.

Comment: @DanielRHicks this is an option but I'd find it very strange they'd bother using two different components for same spec pedals in the low side of their product range. Lighting and bow angle is different in both pictures. According to the specifications I've found on the internet the only difference is in the spring color. Moreover, polished vs. unpolished bows would probably make a difference when clipping them. That's a basic functionality of that product and wouldn't expect any difference.

Comment: Like I said, "price-reduced".  Polishing up the bows costs money and adds little functionality (the difference in finish is unlikely to be noticeable when clipping in/out).  The type of plating on the springs is another cost issue -- chrome plating has become quite expensive with its environmental issues.